# logstash change type format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have ror application that in admin dashboard, admin could observe the location of his employee, in my case, I use elk to gather information of employees that contains latitude and longitude and which send to my map based on his movement, My problem is, I have a template that logstash based on template create daily index but recently I found every field in my index that have type changed to text when indexed created.

this is my json that logstash reads:

```
{"driver_id": 31,"driver_email": "ankith.ravindran@mailinator.com","location": {"latitude": "-35.2824767","longitude": "149.1326453"},"created_at": "2021-06-29 14:28:47", "required_matches": 1, "type": "location"}
```

this is my logstash.conf file:

```
input {
    file {
        path => ["/usr/share/logstash/MPD_LOCATION/*",
                 "/usr/share/logstash/MPD_LOCATION/*/*",
                 "/usr/share/logstash/MPD_LOCATION/*/*/*",
                 "/usr/share/logstash/MPD_LOCATION/*/*/*/*",
                 "/usr/share/logstash/MPD_LOCATION/*/*/*/*/*"]
         start_position => "beginning"
         type => "json"
         sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}


filter {
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message","/}+({)/", "}::{"]
    }
    mutate {
        gsub => ["message","/}+( )/", "}::"]
    }
    split {
        field => "message"
        terminator => "::"
    }
    json { source => "message" }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "uuid" => "D%{driver_id}T%{created_at}" }
        rename => {
                "[location][latitude]" => "[location][lat]"
                "[location][longitude]" => "[location][lon]"
        }
        convert => {
               "[location][lat]" => "float"
               "[location][lon]" => "float"
        }
    }
}
output {
    if ([type] == "location") {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "live_locations_%{+YYYY_MM_dd}"
        # manage_template => true
        template => "/usr/share/logstash/Template/live_locations.json"
        template_name => "live_locations"
        # template_overwrite => true
        document_id => "%{uuid}"
      }
    } else if ([type] == "app_info") {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => "http://elasticsearch:9200"
        index => "app_info_%{+YYYY_MM_dd}"
        document_id => "%{uuid}"
      }
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

this is my template file:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "driver_id": { "type": "integer" },
          "email": { "type": "text" },
          "location": { "type": "geo_point" },
          "app-platform": { "type": "text" },
          "app-version": { "type": "text" },
          "created_at": { "type": "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"},
          "required_matches": { "type": "integer" }
        }
    }
}
```

for example, I defined type of created_at , date but when index created this field return as text and I can't understand what happened or field of location it's return float so I could not use my index as geo_point, I have to add I use elk in the version of 7.13 and used on docker.

Updated : I have two types of JSON that one of them just returns the location of the employee the second of them just returns app_version and app_platform of the employee that used.

Updated 2 : I change my input from logstash to filebeat but I still have the same problem.